# How to update an HTML element on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really new at programming, and I am trying to build a random quote machine. 
The user should be able to get a new random quote upon clicking on a "new quote" button. 
My problem is that I get a new quote the first time I click on the "new quote" button, but then the quote doesn't change anymore upon subsequent clicking events. Can someone identify where the problem is in my code?

Here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="title"> Antsa's Random Quote Machine </h1>

  </div>

  <div class="quote_box">

    <div class="col-xs-12 well quote">
      Quote will go here
    </div>

    <div class="row col-xs-12">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/antsarand" target="_blank"><button class ="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-twitter" id="twitter"></i> </button></a>

      <button id = "newQuote" class = "btn btn-primary">
        New Quote
      </button>
    </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#newQuote").on("click", function() {
     $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(json) {
       var html = "";
       json.forEach(function(val) {

         html += "<div class = 'quote'> ";

         html += "<p class = 'quotation'>" + val.content + val.title + "</p>";

         html += "</div>";
       });
       $(".quote").html(html);
     });

   });
 });
```

Comment: I don't know why the html code doesnt show but here is a link to it: http://codepen.io/arandriamihaja/pen/KzLMbq.

Comment: Hi, welcome, you can read this quick [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines in StackOverflow

Comment: for(var k in json) {
        html += "<div class = 'quote'> ";
        html += "<p class = 'quotation'>" + json[k].content + json[k].title + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't Trust Examples (without checking the Console)**

Your code should work just fine, the Codepen examples do not support cross-origin requests so they were blocking your AJAX calls:

[image]

But if you [use a different example provider like JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hagale/edit?html,output) they should work as expected :

[image]

**Caching Gonna Cache**

If you plan on making multiple requests within the same page, consider disabling caching explicitly through the following statement in your jQuery code :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This will prevent any caching from occurring and ensuring that a new quote is pulled each time.

**Need More?**

Finally, you'll notice that one of your querystring parameters seems to specify exactly how many records to pull `[posts_per_page]=1`. You'll likely need to adjust this if you want to retrieve multiple quotes and actually use your `forEach()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The response from quotesondesign.com is being cached. You need to add `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` somewhere, perhaps `$(document).ready()` or just earlier in your click handler.

Comment: Clearly I have a lot to learn. Thank you very much for your help!